# Superclass as appernt type in list

Tags: java

```
public abstract class class1 {
      int h;
    }

public class class2 extends class1{
      int y;
    }


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello world!");
    List<class1> test;
    test = new ArrayList<class2>();
  }
}
```

I am getting following error 
error: incompatible types: ArrayList cannot be converted to List

Comment: Try changing `<class1>` to `<? extends class1>`

Comment: Try declaring the test variable as `List<? extends class1> test;`